# Twitter Bootstrap - Full-Height Highlight on navbar active links

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use `bootstrap` for a project, and am hitting a problem where I am trying to change the background color of a link marked as `active` in the `navbar`. For reasons I can't seem to track down, there is always a border beneath it that I just can't trim away or get rid of.

I'm not trying to do anything particularly crazy, am I?

### CSS

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a { background-color: #000; }
```

### [Example](http://www.bootply.com/fFosVihY1p#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navbar Default adds a border to the entire menu:

```
.navbar-default {
    border-color: #e7e7e7; 
}
```

To remove it:

```
.navbar-default {
    border: none; 
}
```

or the default `.navbar` border is transparent, which will also work:

```
.navbar-default {
    border: 1px solid transparent; 
}
```

Comment: thank you, I kept looking and looking but there's so many components it gets hard to drill down at times.